# Tailwind CSS - Responsive breakpoints as components

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive, tailwind-css, scss-mixins

How should I deal with responsive breakpoints as components in Tailwind?

Without Tailwind, I used to declare breakpoints as a scss mixins:

```
@mixin tablet-portrait {
  @media (min-width: 700px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
@include tablet-portrait {
  // whatever
}
```

I know that Tailwind has responsive utility clases to use it inline as `md:color-red` but I need to abstract this breakpoins as components, as in above example.

How should I extract Tailwind breakpoints from Tailwind config file?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I found the @screen directive, that solves this question:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives/#screen

as easy as

```
@screen md {
  // whatever
}
```

Update. As mentioned in the comment, Taliwind 3.2.7 has different notation:

```
@media screen(sm) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I'm using this in code today just fine but the current documentation has a new syntax: `@media screen(md) {...}`. It doesn't even mention the `@screen` directive. Not sure if this is a change they'll formalise at some point but if you're reading this answer and it doesn't work, that might be why.

Comment: Heads up: In my default laravel vite setup the first one (`@screen md`) works just fine. The other one does not work.

Answer (score 10):

`@screen md` is not working when using SCSS.
Meanwhile, if you have your breakpoints (`screens` key) set in your `tailwind.config.js`, you can use this

```css
.your-selector {
  // your usual CSS
  @media (min-width: theme('screens.xl.min')) {
    // your media-queried CSS when > xl breakpoint
  }
}
```

Comment: I've found @screen md working fine in SCSS in my setup, but this solution is interesting of note as it can be used to have `max-width` breakpoints without changing the default breakpoint setup: `@media (max-width: theme("screens.md")) { ... }` (note that this is 1px off of perfect, but should work in 99.9% situations).

Answer (score 4):

in tailwind.config.js

```
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
  
  theme: {
    screens: {
      // adding xs to the rest
      xs: "475px",
      // if you did not add this, you would have only "xs"
      ...defaultTheme.screens,
    },
  },
  
};
```

Comment: Instead of pulling in the default theme you can use the "extend" property to allow for the extension of screen sizes...

https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints#custom-media-queries
https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints#extending-the-default-breakpoints
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#adding-larger-breakpoints

Comment: doesn't really answer the main question though

Answer (score 2):

By tailwind You can use and Customizing the default breakpoints for your project.

1. Open your `tailwind.config.js`
2. Update/add `screens` inside your `module.exports`:

   ```js
   theme: {
     screens: {
       'sm': '640px',
       // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... } 

       'md': '768px',
       // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

       'lg': '1024px',
       // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

       'xl': '1280px',
       // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
     }
   }
   ```

Source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints

Comment: doesn't really answer the main question though